# Custom swap function for lists gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault, swap

I'm trying to write a swap function for lists, but one line gives me a segmentation error and I don't know why.

I've tried killing myself but that hasn't worked

```
struct node {
    int inf;
    node* next;
};


node* swapnode(node* head, node* aprev, node* a, node* bprev, node* b)
{
    if(a == b) return head;
    if(a == head)
    {
        node* temp = a->next;
        a->next = b->next;
        b->next = temp;
        bprev->next = a;
        head = b;
        return head;
    }
    if(b == head)
    {
        node* temp = b->next;
        b->next = a->next;
        a->next = temp;
        aprev->next = b;
        head = a;
        return head;
    }
    node* temp;
    temp = a->next;
    a->next = b->next;
    b->next = temp;
    bprev->next = a;
    aprev->next = b;
    return head;

}
```

Looks like the line a->next = b->next gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: It seems to me that the only thing that needs to be done to "swap" a pair of "list"s, is to swap the head and the tail pointers of both lists. Mission accomplished. The lists have been "swap"ped. Unless you mean something different than the classical meaning of "swap". In which case you need to [edit] your question after reviewing the instructions in stackoverflow.com's [help] for creating a [mcve] that anyone can cut/paste, run themselves, and reproduce  your problem and analyze it themselves. Otherwise it's unlikely that anyone can help you.

Comment: Trying to kill oneself is rarely helpful.  Have you tried anything else?  :-)

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to swap two elements of one list, a and b being pointers to those elements while aprev and bprev pointers to the elements before them. If i change the line a->next = b->next to a->next = anything else the programs doesn't give out a seg-fault.

Comment: Why can't you use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)?

Comment: Pretty sure I can't use swap since the lists I implemented don't have random access operators []

Comment: Without a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll go out on a limb: if the fault really happens at `a->next = b->next`, then I suspect that `a` or `b` is null, due to a mistake in the code you haven't shown. **But there is another bug: consider what happens if a->next=b.**

Comment: Rather than physically relinking nodes, it would be so much easier to just swap the payload, `inf`